# Possible to group by a user metadata label that includes dashes, in MQL?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I am trying to use MQL queries to export data from Google Cloud Monitoring to BigQuery for long-term archiving. I've found that queries that group-by user generated metadata labels including a dash character (e.g "wdl-call-alias") do not seem to be compatible with MQL. I rely on a third-party system that generates these labels and they are not easy to change.

Is there a way to use MQL to group-by metadata labels that include dashes? I've included two cases below, for reference.

Working query using "sample" label:

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores'
| group_by 1m, [value_reserved_cores_mean: mean(value.reserved_cores)]
| every 1m
| group_by [metadata.user.sample: metadata.user_labels.sample],
    [value_reserved_cores_mean_aggregate: aggregate(value_reserved_cores_mean)]
```

Broken query using "wdl-call-alias" label:

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores'
| group_by 1m, [value_reserved_cores_mean: mean(value.reserved_cores)]
| every 1m
| group_by [metadata.user.wdl-call-alias: metadata.user_labels.wdl-call-alias],
    [value_reserved_cores_mean_aggregate: aggregate(value_reserved_cores_mean)]
```

Comment: you can try to rename your rows with `map`

Comment: or just try quoting them, eg: `| group_by ['metadata.user.wdl-call-alias': 'metadata.user_labels.wdl-call-alias'], `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the syntax:  `metadata.user_labels.c'wdl-call-alias'`

Metadata uses the same syntax as column labels (it is kind of a pseudo-column), and column label components that are not identifiers need to be quoted using the `c'....'` or `c"...."` syntax.

So:

```
| group_by [metadata.user.wdl-call-alias: metadata.user_labels.c'wdl-call-alias'],
    [value_reserved_cores_mean_aggregate: aggregate(value_reserved_cores_mean)]
```

Or more compactly:

```
| group_by [metadata.user_labels.c'wdl-call-alias'], .aggregate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your rows in a separate `map` call, or inline in the `group_by`:

From https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-groupby-aggr

> The `group_by` operation takes two arguments, separated by a comma `,`. These arguments determine the precise grouping behavior.
>
> The first argument controls the grouping of time series. This is a *map expression*, [...] The map expression can do much more than list labels; for more information, see the [`map` reference page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#map).

You can read the full doc there, but TLDR is:

The syntax of `map` is `map : [ modifier ] '[' [ maplet { ',' maplet } ] ']'`, the "modifier" you need is `rename`, and the "maplet" should be:

```
maplet : [ column_name ':' ] expr .
column_name : ID | QUOTED_COLUMN .
```

ie: "column_name" which can be quoted!

so,

`| map rename ['metadata.user.wdl-call-alias': 'metadata.user.wdl_call_alias']` should give you the result you want.

*But i don't have a GCP account right now to test it.*